# examples of different metrical feet/accents (scansion)

Tags: poetry

I enjoy writing poetry in strict meter (example: iambic pentameter), but I keep running into an issue with word choice.  I lack a reference for words and the way they are accented.  I am wondering if there is a compendium that lists different types of words (in terms of stress). For example, the following words have trochaic rhythm (/u):

```
 legend 
 double
 ember
```

And these words have iambic rhythm (u/):

```
 attempt 
 compare
 until
```

Ideally, word choice would come first, but I prefer the restrictions in play when writing in meter.  Perhaps it is my job as the poet to sound out various words aloud and decide where the stresses are . . . but some words are very ambiguous or subject to an individual's way of speaking, no?  I am wondering if there is a "word bank" for various types of rhythm for me to draw from when writing in specific meters.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I'm  not sure about accent, I just use dictionary.com or m-w.com (Merriam-Webster's site) and look for the diacritical marks or bolded syllables. For example, "legend" has [ **lej**-uhnd ]. I also find it useful for words that my ear wants to make two syllables but that are actually one, like "wild". My ear wants "wy-uld" but the dictionary has [ wahyld ] -- one vowel makes one syllable.

Comment: \ ˈle-jənd  is what I see on merriam webster.  No bold.  I was thinking the slash meant something, but the same dash appears for "attempt" which has the opposite stress: \ ə-ˈtem(p)t.   Thoughts?

Comment: Merriam-webster uses an accent mark (apostrophe) at the beginning of the emphasized syllable. Something like ab-so-'luh-shun for absolution. I think the bold on dictionary.com is easier to see.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this would be a good use of AI? I am a musician, and would like to be able to write lyrics in a text editor that can analyze the meter of the words I use as I write, and/or have it analyze the meter of words already written. Alternately, the editor could generate a rhythm and help me find words that fit within the established meter (or at least suggest the meter of the next word I need to write).

This generated meter could be output as MIDI data and fed into, say, a drum machine or synthesizer to come up with rhythms that complement the lyrics.